# Remove ChromeOS and change OS to Ubuntu on Lenovo (ARM) S330 Chromebook from USB boot

Tags: boot, usb, lenovo, arm

I'm trying to change the OS of my Lenovo S330 Chromebook for Ubuntu, I'm a noob sorry for that :)

**Here's my version :**

Google Chrome   78.0.3889.0 (Build officiel) dev (32 bits)
Révision    3d2d95af816d281f7b8f58c37509c53e913a2cc5-refs/branch-heads/3889@{#1}
Plate-forme 12447.0.0 (Official Build) dev-channel hana
Version du micrologiciel    Google_Hana.8438.180.0
ID de la personnalisation   OEM1-MAPLE14
ARC 5818192
JavaScript  V8 7.8.135
Flash   32.0.0.238 /opt/google/chrome/pepper/libpepflashplayer.so
Agent utilisateur   Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS aarch64 12447.0.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3889.0 Safari/537.36

**Here's my system:**

CHROME VERSION

78.0.3889.0 dev
CHROMEOS_ARC_ANDROID_SDK_VERSION

25
CHROMEOS_ARC_STATUS

disabled
CHROMEOS_ARC_VERSION

5818192
CHROMEOS_AUSERVER

https://tools.google.com/service/update2
CHROMEOS_BOARD_APPID

{AAE972E1-A913-C860-B7AB-BF7F267F199B}
CHROMEOS_CANARY_APPID

{90F229CE-83E2-4FAF-8479-E368A34938B1}
CHROMEOS_DEVSERVER

CHROMEOS_FIRMWARE_VERSION

Google_Hana.8438.180.0
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_APPID

{AAE972E1-A913-C860-B7AB-BF7F267F199B}
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_BOARD

hana-signed-mp-v5keys
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_BRANCH_NUMBER

0
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_BUILDER_PATH

hana-release/R78-12447.0.0
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_BUILD_NUMBER

12447
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_BUILD_TYPE

Official Build
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_CHROME_MILESTONE

78
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_DESCRIPTION

12447.0.0 (Official Build) dev-channel hana 
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_KEYSET

mp-v5
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_NAME

Chrome OS
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_PATCH_NUMBER

0
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_TRACK

dev-channel
CHROMEOS_RELEASE_VERSION

12447.0.0
CLIENT_ID

4db98720-0e76-4ca2-bb02-4299a3dbad7f 
DEVICETYPE

CHROMEBOOK
ENTERPRISE_ENROLLED

Not managed
GOOGLE_RELEASE

---

As you can see here , I'm not able to have Seabios and boot from usb device and erase chromeOS to Ubuntu as

[command lines from John Lewis and MrChromebox do not work on ARM chromebooks]

[Custom Firmware/Availability Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sxgxe.png)

I just want to be able to remove completly Chrome OS, and install a stable version of Linux, no crouton, nor dual OS.

Thanks a lot for your help and answers, have a good one!!Best Regards

I just want to be able to remove completly Chrome OS, and install a stable version of Linux, no crouton, nor dual OS.

Thanks a lot for your help and answers, have a good one!!Best Regards

Comment: This is something easier said then done. I doubt you'll be able to do it.

Comment: @mikewhatever i did not think it was that hard, thanks for your answer